# SAPUI5 writes complete DOM again and not delta?

Tags: sapui5

In comparison to other new frameworks, I have observed SAP UI5 writes the complete DOM again while loading an application instead of updating the delta.

My questions are:

> - Is it done intentionally by the framework for some benefits?
> - It causes the app to load relatively slower.